# in cygwin(bash scripting idk) how to create a new .sh file like we do in unix nano fileName.sh

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am using Cygwin. I want to create a new `.sh` file and execute it. But I  do not know how to create a `.sh` file with Cygwin which is IDK for Windows for Bash scripting.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you asking which text editors are available in Cygwin? That depends on the packages you have installed. I'd be surprised if `nano` wasn't available.

Comment: You don't have to create the file with Cygwin.  You can just create it using normal Windows text editors such as Notepad++.

Comment: A question about editing a file as a manual process -- rather than an automated process -- is a better fit for SuperUser than StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, ...to be fair, that depends on how cygwin is configured with respect to DOS newline conversion; it's not necessarily true.

Comment: What does "idk" mean (other than "I don't know")?

Answer (score 0):

Bash and Cygwin don't really care how you create your files, or prescribe a particular way.  Any editor should be fine, as long as you make sure it can save text files with U*x line endings (as opposed to DOS line endings, which use CR+LF for end of line).  Popular Windows editors include Notepad++ and SublimeText (which exists for other platforms too); traditional Unix editors include Emacs and `vi` as well as `nano`.  In the trivial case, you can create a script right in Bash itself.

```
you@cygwin:~$ cat >script
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello, World!"
^D

you@cygwin:~$ chmod +x ./script

you@cygwin:~$ ./script
Hello, World!
```

(You would press and hold down the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key while pressing <kbd>D</kbd> to create ctrl-D above.)

Comment: i made a .sh files                                #!/bin/bash
echo "welcome"
sleep 1s
echo "byee"
read ans
echo $ans                                    when i tried to run it error is coming Try 'sleep --help' for more information.

Comment: What you call it is even less important; the [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is the usual way to direct the kernel to use a particular scripting language to read your script.